# How to learn status of bankruptcy?

Tags: united-states, california, bankruptcy

I was a contractor for a company that went bankrupt seven months ago. I am still owed money. I have not heard from the bankruptcy lawyers.

How can I find out the status of the bankruptcy, who the lawyers are, and anything else I should know?

The company was based in California, USA. I live here too.  I am aware that I may not get the money I was owed, but I want to confirm that I'm at least in the loop.

Also, I have not received a 1099 form for the money I **was** paid. Must I learn who their accountants were in order to get it?

Answer (score 3):

Don't worry about the 1099. Report your gross income and include a note with the return that states: (1) the name/address of the company, (2) that they went bankrupt so have not provided you with a 1099. That's all you have to do.

Once a company goes bankrupt, they don't have to pay their contractors. Unless the company has significant assets (which is unlikely) your chance of recovery is zero, unless you are capable of devising very creative legal strategies on your own, which is also unlikely. Therefore, your best action is just to move on to the next job.

If you are curious about the state of the bankruptcy or want to see the filings, contact the clerk of the court. There are four bankruptcy courts in California. For companies in Los Angeles, the Central District Bankruptcy Court would be handling the filing. [The creditor information web site for that court has information on how to submit a claim electronically and get information about the bankruptcy](https://www.cacb.uscourts.gov/creditors).

Comment: The type of bankruptcy filing has some bearing.  As a contractor, Shawn might be classified as a creditor.  Chapter 7/11/13 distinguish who gets paid first, creditors or investors, or specify reorganization.  I can't remember which is which but that's easily discovered.  If it's investors first, probably can forget recovering much of anything owed.